# Как на arduino/esp8266 преобразовать входящий cvbs сигнал в видео и сохранить на sd карте

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp8266

У меня есть камера и мне нужно сохранить видео с неë на sd карту в формате mp4

[image]

Подготовка

- Подключаю **cvbs +** к пину **A0** а **cvbs -** к **gnd**
- Красный провод подключаю к блоку питания
- Загружаю прошивку

```
void start() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int value = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(value);
}
```

После запуска в консоль выводятся значения
*Например: 346 528 268 1021 638 275 260 102 104 1020 ...*

- Как эти значения преобразовать в полноценный кадр

Comment: Задача состоит из трёх независимых: 1) Сформировать из аналогового сигнала в буфере полный кадр (картинку). 2) Собрать из последовательности картинок видео в формате mp4 3) Сохранить данные на SD-карту

Comment: @ГерманБорисов
Я это понял ещё до того как задал вопрос 1) А как именно преобразовать сигнал в картинку, я просто видел что надо **cvbs +** подключять на два пина через резисторы 2) И эти значения может в двоичный код перевести или еще во что-то надо, просто ничего не смог найти связанное с arduino и **cvbs**

Comment: http://www.batsocks.co.uk/readme/video_timing.htm вот тут хорошо расписано как выглядит сигнал cvbs. Например, одна строка пикселей передаётся 64 микросекунды. А analogRead у arduino выполняется 104 микросекунды. Задача не реализуема.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов то есть камера отправит допустим 2 строки а arduino примет только 1.625 пикселя? А какая скорость у esp8266? И может есть какой нибудь модуль? (на модуле камеры есть же пин **tx** как там передаются данные)

Comment: Нужно смотреть спецификацию камеры. На тех что видел по uart (rx/tx) передаются команды вкл /выкл / сделать снимок / передать снимок в формате jpeg и ещё что-то.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов а чем можно заменить arduino есть какие нибудь другие контроллеры подходящие для этого (контроллер принимает и сохраняет сигнал на sd карту а arduino/esp8266 уже делают что надо)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов https://pikabu.ru/story/arduino_mogla_byit_v_25_raz_byistree_raznitsa_skorosti_arduino_vs_avr_vs_stm32_5666145 а это может ускорить считывание  аналогового пина?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Ну я тут почитал и короче буду создавать свой процессор